# Remove Duplicates using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete duplicate entries from each column, I am successful in doing it for one column C but I want to do it from A to Column Z. I have tried to change myCol to variable long & wrote column number but it is giving me an error (so that I can run number loop). Here is my code:

```
Sub test()
Dim myCol As String

myCol = "C"

With Sheets("Union")
    lastrow = .Range(myCol & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(myCol & "1:" & myCol & lastrow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I have a small doubt.. You want to remove duplicates from say **[1.]** `Range("A1:O23")` or **[2.]** From each column individually? If it is "1" then the complete row will be matched with the other rows...

Comment: Each column is separate & nothing to do with other.

Comment: ok. then in that case, Dean's answer will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try creating a `For` loop accounting for A-Z as integers. I am not sure that this is the most efficient solution, but it could work for you. See below.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim myCol As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long

    For myCol = 1 To 26
        With Sheets("Union")
            lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, myCol).End(xlUp).Row

            If lastrow >= 3 Then
                .Range(.Cells(1, myCol), .Cells(lastrow, myCol)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
            End If
        End With
    Next myCol

End Sub
```

**EDIT**: Tested, and working as required.

**SECOND EDIT**: Added in a `lastrow` check to ensure there is some data in the column before trying to remove duplicates. 3 because that would mean at least 2 entries in that column, the minimum for there to be a need to check for duplicates.

Comment: Dear, it is giving me Apllication defined error on this line ".Range(.Cells(1, myCol), .Cells(lastrow, myCol)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes"

Comment: If you use `Debug.Print` for `lastrow` and `myCol` what are they when you receive this error?

Comment: my Col is 2 last row is 1, actually, at some columns, I have data and some columns I don't have data i think this may be the issue

Comment: That is exactly your issue my friend. I will adjust the code above to try take this into account.

Comment: @UmarFarooq please check the above edit. If this works for you, please accept as answer to close the ticket :)

Comment: @Dean, the minimum for doubles would be 2 entries. With the header included, that's three rows, so `If lastrow > 2 Then`. Very picky, sorry :). Otherwise +1

Comment: @JvdV the `.RemoveDuplicates` does not reference the header if `Headers:=xlYes`. So minimum with this set to yes would be 3. `Headers:=xlYes` means that the data has a header and will not be used. Run a check and see. Let me know after that and I will correct, but based on my test that was the case. :)

Comment: Ok dear checking

Comment: @Dean, header is row 1, data is row 2 and 3. So lastrow must be either `>=3` or `>2`. Check with this data: `Header1,A,A` from row 1:3. :). It will currently skip a column with just two rows of data and a header.